# How to output the order where at least one column is filled with all positive number

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I want to create a formula to output the order, where at least one column is filled with all positive values. In this case, the result should be order 11 and 12. Thank you.

[image]

```
order      a      b     c
11         1      1     2
11         1     -1    -3
12        -2      1    -1
12         1      1     3
13         2      3     2
13        -1     -2    -3
```

Comment: Why not 13 as 13 has also all positive value?

Comment: Not 13 because michael stipulated that an order must have at least one positive "column" to be eligible. Each column to the right of 13 has one negative (-3,-2,-3)

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$6)/(($B$2:$B$7>0)*($C$2:$C$7>0)*($D$2:$D$7>0)),ROW(1:1)),COLUMN(A$1)),"")
```

[image]